# How to do paging in WebAPI MVC 4 using BreezeJs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have a WebApi controleller, and added the filters from BreezeJs to support queryable requests like $orderby=DateAdded&$top=8.

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(
      new Breeze.WebApi.ODataActionFilter());
```

everything works fine. This only give 8 results. What do i need to do to add such the total count is also returned with the result?

UPDATE

```
 public class ODataHandler : DelegatingHandler
  {
      protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
          return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
            task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;

                if (ResponseIsValid(response) && ShouldInlineCount(request))
                {
                    object responseObject;
                    response.TryGetContentValue(out responseObject);

                    if (responseObject is IQueryable)
                    {
                        var renum = responseObject as IEnumerable<object>;

                        if (renum != null)
                        {
                            response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ODataMetadata<object>(renum, renum.Count()));
                        }
                    }
                }

                return response;
            });
      }
      private bool ShouldInlineCount(HttpRequestMessage request)
      {

        var queryParams = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();

        var inlinecount = queryParams["$inlinecount"];

        return string.Compare(inlinecount, "allpages", true) == 0;

       }

      private bool ResponseIsValid(HttpResponseMessage response)
      {
          if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK || !(response.Content is ObjectContent)) return false;
          return true;
      }
  }
```

This is what i came up with so far. But problem is that the filter have already added teh TOP 8 to the request before the handler kicks in. So count will be 8 and not total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question. The OData support in the current version of Breeze does not understand the  [$inlinecount parameter for OData 2.0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#InlinecountSystemQueryOption) which, I think, is what you are looking for. It is on the backlog. Please vote up that [idea on the Breeze user voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3273039-support-inlinecount-in-queries).

Comment: I just asked for the same thing on their forum. Just vent over the code, its maybe 5 lines to add to their ODataActionFilter

Comment: $inlinecount is supported as of v.0.75.1